# Query failed with error code 13 and error message

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

Tengo un problema en un proyecto de Spring boot 2.0.3.RELEASE + mongodb 4

**- Instancie mi DB como**

```
mongod --auth --config mongod.conf --dbpath=\data\mongo4\
```

**- Cree el usuario de las siguientes dos maneras**

```
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "us1",
    pwd: "abc123",
    roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "dbTest" }]
  }
)

db.createUser(
  {
    user: "us2",
    pwd: "abc123",
    roles: [ 
        { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },
        { role: "root", db: "admin" },
        { role: "readWrite", db: "dbTest" }
    ]
  }
)
```

**- En mi archivo application.properties fue configurado así**

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=dbTest
spring.data.mongodb.username=user
spring.data.mongodb.password=pass
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=dbTest
```

Sin embargo, el error que me muestra en Spring es el siguiente:

```
org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Query failed with error code 13 and error message 'command find requires authentication' on server localhost:27017; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 13 and error message 'command find requires authentication' on server localhost:27017
```

He buscado el error pero no logro arreglarlo

Answer (score 0):

Te entrega error de autenticación debido a que no estás proporcionando los datos de usuario y contraseña que corresponden a las de tus usuarios creados.

```
spring.data.mongodb.username=user
spring.data.mongodb.password=pass
```

Estas configuraciones no tienen como valor `us1` o `us2` que son los usuarios que creaste, ni tampoco la contraseña `abc123`.

Answer (score 0):

espero que mi respuesta te sirva de ayuda.(Lo primero a comentar es que si puedes indica las dependencias que tienes respecto a lo que tenga que ver con mongodb así facilita más la búsqueda)

**spring.data.mongodb.host** y **spring.data.mongodb.port** no son compatibles si utiliza el controlador **Java de Mongo 3.0**.

En tales casos, spring.data.mongodb.uri debe usarse para proporcionar toda la configuración, así:

`spring.data.mongodb.uri =Ejemplo: mongodb: // usuario: secret@mongo1.example.com: 12345`

Estructura de la uri:`mongodb://<user>:<passwd>@<host>:<port>/<dbname>`

Espero que te sirva de ayuda saludos!!